# Replacing existing record with a newly created but unsaved record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have record A which has been saved in the database, then I want to replace it with a newly created record B which **has not been saved**. So B can then be saved in the database but with the id of from A (and A is replaced). Is this possible in Rails Active Record?

P.S. the reason behind this is that I need to merge objects by some condition, and constructing an object requires some internet fetching/parsing. So if time is used to parse B I want to prevent parsing it again for A, but replacing it with B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
a = A.find(1)
b = B.new

# Modify b

a.update_attributes(b.attributes.delete_if{ |k,v| %w(id created_at updated_at).include?(k) })
```

Comment: This answer is just a bit more complete (created_at won't be nil). Thanks!

Comment: Since you are copying parameters from new, not saved records `created_at` and `update_at` are not filling yet.

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin, I thought of the same solution as you, but when I tried it in console I got a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, created_at, updated_at` error. That's why I deleted those attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this(didn't test this code):

```
a = Model.find(params[:id])
b = Model.new(params)
a.update_attributes(b.attributes)
```